# How long it takes to start an Activity?

Tags: android

I am working in android application.I have one doubt "How long it takes to start an

Activity?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you mean in the emulator?? depends on your machines specification, and also on the application size you want to load, in average the first load takes a lot like  1 or 2 minutes it is because it must load all the emulator setting turn the phone configuration on and a bunch stuff more... if the the emulator is on then it should take no more than 10 seconds to actually start your application running.

Answer (score 3):

Depends on the speed of the device.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question: it depends.

- Slower/older hardware will take longer to start an `Activity` than new hardware.
- If the target device is already running a lot of applications then the OS could have to kill them before your app can start, which could cause a delay.
- If you are performing some intensive tasks in your `onCreate` method then it will take a long time to start, and might not start at all if the OS decides it is taking too long.